# some page of sharepoint not load

Tags: site-collection

suddenly some of sharepoint page(site settings page) not load.
some page as like "change the look" or "add an app" not load.the page load and show progress screen but not load completely.
I create new site collection and it work fine.I export my site collection and create a new site collation and import the exported site collection,but not work.
**Update**:
Ifound solution.if I copy oslo.master from other site collaction, it work fine but sharepoint bar not shown and master file not show properly.Now i need fix my master files (oslo and seattel) by going to back.anybody have Idea?

Comment: Please check your log while loading the page and maybe try to IIS reset

Comment: So please post the errors within your question

Comment: I reset IIS ,reset the application pool and check the log with ULS.only show 2 error :"Failed to get document content data "and "Could not get DocumentContent row: 0x80004005." i think is not related to my problem

Comment: should I check any where else?

Comment: and other exception :UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized

Comment: other log I found newly : SPRequest.GetWebMetainfo: UserPrincipalName=, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://xx/sites/xxxx

Comment: any body has idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 5  day hard work ,now I found solution! On sharpoint designer ,on master pages right click on every master page files(oslo.master - seattel.master and htmls) and click  on  "reset to site definition".